# Why doesn't "add" work here? "If a little tomato sauce is **add** to it, its taste will definitely improve."

Tags: conditional-constructions, sentence-structure

> If a little tomato sauce is .... to it, its taste will definitely improve.

I think that "add" should go in the blank.

But, according to what I understand in this sentence I cannot use add here because it is not forming a grammatically correct sentence and I have no clue what else to use.

Please correct me if i am wrong

Comment: A correct answer woukd be *is added*.

Comment: @Sander Yes,but why the verb(add) changed to past.it sounds correct but i don't think we should violate the rule.

Comment: It is not a past, it is a passive verb. The tomato sauce cannot add itself, someone or soemthing else performs the action.

Comment: @Sander Okay i need to remember this form of sense..

Comment: And -very important - the second 'its' corresponds to the first 'it', showing the need for a passive construction. Not the tomato sauce, but the 'it' will taste better.

Comment: The active (non-passive) version of the sentence is "If I/you/they add a little tomato sauce to it, its taste will definitely improve". The passive voice allows you to use a verb like "add" without saying who is doing the adding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question is *is added*.

> If a little tomato sauce *is added* to it, its taste will definitely improve.

Your title and first line differ, and I was going off the first line with *is added*. If using only your title, the answer would be just *added*.